# telethon Как отвечать в комментариях telegram?

Tags: python, telethon

Я хочу что бы программа отвечала в канале от имени пользователя в комментариях на пост в котором имеется знак + словом "lol".
Я написал код но у меня вылезает ошибка: telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MsgIdInvalidError: The message ID used in the peer was invalid (caused by GetDiscussionMessageRequest) в `await client.send_message(event.chat, message="lol", comment_to=event.post)` А именно в `event.chat`
код:

```
 @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats= id_tg_chanel))
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            if '+' in event.raw_text:
                await client.send_message(event.chat, message="lol", comment_to=event.post) #Именно тут в event.chat
                await client.disconnect()
                
        client.run_until_disconnected()
```

я пытался ещё вместо `send_message` использовать `await event.reply('lol')`, но тогда программа пытается ответить в самом канале(Тем более мне не хватает прав писать в канале), а мне надо чтобы отвечала в комментариях.
Буду очень благодарен!